# Lumix GH5 -- Blue Grains in Preview Screen

Tags: exposure, camera-settings, panasonic-lumix

I have been trying to find an answer to this all over the place. I haven't been successful so far, hence, coming here in hopes that someone has experienced a similar issue. I'm an owner of a GX8 and most recently a GH5, and both seem to have the same issues with the preview screen.

80% of the time when I'm shooting outdoors, pointing my camera at objects, a "blue grain" appears which disturbs my ability to see the shot clearly from the camera itself. As far as I have noticed, the issue seems to happen the most when it is really sunny outside, meaning that it could be exposure related.

Someplace else, someone had written that it might be related to the "zebra" settings, which I played around with, but with no success.

Unfortunately, the weather today is poor and during my testing, I didn't see any "grain" come up. Either way, maybe some of you are aware of this particular issue and know how to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me, you're seeing this effect in the viewfinder? If so, is the effect also in the recorded image?

Comment: Could this be focus peaking ?  Sounds somewhat like the effect you'd see in the viewfinder on on screen with peaking.

Comment: Yep, in the viewfinder. But it also shows up on the actual camera screen. The effect does not appear in the recorded image/video. Hmm, Stephen, could you elaborate more on focus peaking?

Comment: Here's a [Panasonic video about GH5 about focus peaking](http://eng-ca.faq.panasonic.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43093/~/operational-video---lumix-dc-gh5---how-to-use-focus-peaking)

Comment: Sounds like you turned on Focus Peaking and that 20% of the time your images were out of focus!